Optimizing a process in several steps : how to train a model if we use it several times before being able to calculate the loss?
I have a process in a certain number of steps ; let's say 3.

We start with an initialized null matrix M0 which describes the state of our system, and have to take an action which consequences are random but strongly influenced by the action
We update the matrix (M1), and again take an action
We again update the matrix (M2), take a last action
Only now we can calculate the loss from the last matrix M3, so we have the evaluation of our strategy

I have built a Neural Network where the matrix of the state is the input, and the output is a list of weights that decides which action to take. From my (beginner) understanding the whole looks a bit like a recurrent Neural Network but with extra steps.
I implemented the process in Python but when I try to train the model the GradientTape() doesn't look happy as the gradient is never calculated for my variables ; I'm not sure but I think the randomness of the loss makes the gradient not computable (computing the loss from the weights is far from being straightforward, as the weights are put on edges of a graph and we perform algorithms on it).
I have thought of doing Reinforcement Learning without the list of weights to take the action, however I don't know how well the randomness of the reward will work. Also, I have never done such a thing and I have only a week to implement everything. The space of actions is also pretty big so there is a lot of uncertainty with this method.
Is there any common practice on how to tackle this kind of problem ?

" I have a process in a certain number of steps ". This is the definition of the problem? Clearly define the problem, before jumping into any solution. " how to tackle this kind of problem?" We don't know what problem you're solving.
